# Nested ForEach function in typescript does not recognize atribute

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to calculate the total of a master-detail model.

```
  calcularTotales() {
this.dataSource.data.forEach(function (ingreso) {
  console.log(ingreso);
  ingreso.detalleIngreso.forEach(function (detalle) {
    detalle.total = detalle.precio * detalle.cantidad;
    ingreso.totalIngreso += detalle.total;
  });
});}
```

The problem comes when I try to iterate **ingreso.detalleIngreso**, it says that detalleIngreso is undefined. However in the console.log(ingreso) it appears:

[output of **console.log(ingreso)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwQVN.png)

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks!!!

Comment: The property is `detalleIngresos` not `detalleIngreso`.

Comment: @Ploppy I had the class atribute as `detalleIngreso` but it I changed it and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the attribute of the class to `detalleIngresos` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the context convert your function declarations to arrow syntax.